# Meaning of derivative of a function with respect to another function

Tags: calculus

In chain rule we use,$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz} \times \frac{dz}{dx}$. My question is what is meant by $\frac{dy}{dz}$.When we find derivative,we find it with respect to an independent vairable meaning if $x$ changes by some amount,how much does $f(x)$ changes.But how much $g(f(x))$ changes by a change in $f(x)$ doesn't seem to make sense to me.Also derivatives are all about slopes of a graph.Now we will we draw the graph of $g(f(x))$ vs $f(x)$ since we can't place $f(x)$ on real axis as it can't achieve all real numbers for it being a dependent variable.So could someone please shed some light on what we are actually doing?

Comment: That's just the ratio of their differentials.

Comment: And derivatives aren't *all* about slopes of graphs. That's just one way to interpret them. You would do yourself a great disservice to think otherwise.

Comment: To answer your question about the chain rule, the fraction $dy/dz$ is the derivative of $y$ with regard to the *independent* variable $z,$ and $dz/dx$ is that of $z$ with regard to the independent variable $x.$ This is why the chain rule is not a trivial statement, since the $z$'s have different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric idea: for $h,k$ small we have
$$x = x_0 + h\implies f(x)\approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h.$$
$$y = y_0 + k\implies g(y)\approx g(y_0) + g'(y_0)k.$$
Then, if $y = f(x), y_0 = f(x_0)$:
$$
g(f(x))\approx g(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h)\approx
g(f(x_0)) + g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)h.
$$

Comment: In the last part,how do we get the last approximation?

Comment: @AritraBarua, I will edit for greater clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example: let's say we have a variable $V$ representing volume, and another variable $T$ representing temperature. Now the rate of change of volume with respect to temperature is given by $\frac{dV}{dT}$. If we further suppose that $T$ depends on another variable $t$ representing time, then the rate of change of volume with respect to time can be found by $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dT}\cdot \frac{dT}{dt}$$

Comment: My concern is regarding graphs and what we mean by the derivative of a function wrt to another function,unfortunately,your example doesn't answer that